# Не валидный JSON,разделить объекты запятыми

Tags: php, json, объекты

Всем добрый возникла следующая проблема.

```html
{"0":"1","ID":"1","1":"2017-10-21 12:39:23","Date":"2017-10-21 12:39:23","2":"Student1","Name":"Student1","3":"student1@stud.com","Email":"student1@stud.com","4":"89123456789","Phone":"89123456789","5":"\u042d\u0423-119","Group":"\u042d\u0423-119","6":"\u041f\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f","Comment":"\u041f\u043e\u0436\u0435\u043b\u0430\u043d\u0438\u044f"}
{"0":"2","ID":"2","1":"2017-10-21 20:20:49","Date":"2017-10-21 20:20:49","2":"\u0441\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0435\u0439","Name":"\u0441\u0435\u0440\u0433\u0435\u0439","3":"sad@dsfsd.com","Email":"sad@dsfsd.com","4":"89222222222","Phone":"89222222222","5":"\u042d\u0423-119","Group":"\u042d\u0423-119","6":"rrr","Comment":"rrr"}
```

Два объекта не разделены запятой.

```html
<?php
    
  $host="";
  $user="";
  $pass=""; //установленный вами пароль
  $db_name="";
    
  $link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
  mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);

  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Student", $link);
  while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo json_encode($result); 
  }
```

Как их разделить запятой ни как не пойму.Суть в том что данные я подгружаю с базы и может быть и 4 и 5 объектов и т.д.

Comment: Так это вывод двух массивов, они и заключены в скобках. Если нужно добавить запятую добавьте через все тоже echo или print.

Comment: Ругается на var res = jQuery.parseJSON(data)

Comment: Ну правильно, парсить нужно один вывод а не все.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сохраните данные в список (можно добавлять функцией array_push), а затем преобразуйте в JSON функцией json_encode.

```
$arr = array('');
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    array_push($arr, $result);
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: теперь ругается syntax error, unexpected T_WHILE, expecting ',' or ';' in

Comment: Добавил точку с запятой после аргумента команды echo.

Comment: @Сергей, используйте вариант номер 2 из ответа, так как вариант номер 1 дает не валидный json, а массив!

Comment: @Visman, я так понимаю мне нужно создать массив добавить данные с помощью array_push и преоброзавать массив json_encode?

Comment: `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Student", $link);
$arr = array('');
$res = array_push($arr, $sql)
 echo json_encode($res);` так это должно выглядеть

Comment: первый способ никуда не годится, будет лишняя запятая после последнего элемента. лучше перепишите ответ и опишите второй вариант, он единственно рабочий (если без костылей)

Comment: @Mike, чуть выше написал, но не уверен что правильно

Comment: @Mike, как это внутри цикл fetch?
`while($row = $sql->fetch()) {
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($row)){

    echo json_encode($result); 

};
}`

Comment: @Сергей Я решил не дожидаться автора ответа и дописал в ответ :)